# How to solve cross and scalar product equation knowing length and angle

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

We have two vectors $a$ and vector $b$. they are both non zero vectors and the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Their lenghts are connected with equation $|b| = \sqrt{3}|a|$

We need to solve this equation (*...scalar product, $\times$... cross product):

[image]

I find it very hard since I know that scalar product is not associative.

My try:
$$ (x*a+x*b)*a + x \times b = 2a\times b + 3|a|^{2}b\\
(x*a)*a+(x*b)*a + x \times b = 2a\times b + 3|a|^{2}b$$
If I solve the distance of $2a\times b$, I get nowhere. I do not know hot to continue.

The solution is $x = 2a+ \frac{2}{9}b+ 2a\times b $

Comment: Please check that $x*(a+b)*a$ is meaning less  if $*$ is dot .

Comment: @ZAhmed I understand. In my case $a*b$ means $<a,b>$.

Comment: @ZAhmed I didn't want to use paranthesis, because some people didn't know that it means scalar product a while back.

Comment: I mean two stars in that first part do not make a sense.

Comment: @ZAhmed I pasted the original problem equation, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data gives $\vec a. \vec b=a^2$.
Let $\vec x= u\vec a+v \vec b+ w (\vec a \times \vec  b).$
where $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are non-collinear. Inserting it in the equation
$$[\vec x.(\vec a+\vec b)]\vec a+\vec x \times \vec b= 2\vec a\times \vec b + 3a^2\vec b.$$
$$ [\{u \vec a + v \vec b+ w(\vec a\times \vec b)\}.(\vec a + \vec b)].\vec a+ [u\vec a+v \vec b+ w (\vec a \times \vec  b)]\times \vec b=2 \vec a \times \vec b +3a^2 \vec b$$
In this Eq. One has to compare the co-efficients of the bases $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec a \times \vec b$ to get the scalars $u,v,w$. One can make use of $(\vec a \times \vec b)\times \vec b= (\vec a. \vec b)\vec b-b^2 \vec a.$ and $\vec a.(\vec a \times \vec b)=0.$

I hope to come back.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $a$, $b$, and $2a\times b$ is a basis.  Let
$$x=\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma (2a\times b).$$
Multiply out and compare coefficients; use that $3\|a\|^2=\|b\|^2$ and $2\langle a,b\rangle=\|b\|^2$.